# QProcess always returns -2 when running a valid command

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am writing a program in qt that will execute commands in windows.

Here is the method I am using to try to get the commands to work.

```
bool FirmwareUpdater::RunCommand( QString& command, QStringList& args, int expectedCode )
{
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
    proc->setWorkingDirectory ( "C:\\windows\\" );
    int exitCode = proc->execute(command, args );
    proc->waitForFinished();
    this->stream << command << " " << exitCode << "\n";
    return ( exitCode == expectedCode );
}
```

If I run

```
QString command = "ping";
QStringList args;

args << "localhost";
RunCommand( command, args );
```

It works fine and it returns 0;

But if I try any other windows utility it returns -2. Right now im trying to get pnpUtil too work.

```
QString command = qgetenv( "WINDIR" ) + "\\System32\\PnPUtil.exe";
QStringList args;

args << "-a";
args << updateDriver;
```

I have the code print the command with the arguments out to me and if I run the command manually it works. But in qt it doesn't.

Perhaps i'm doing something wrong. Is there any other way of doing this without QProcess?

I have also tried calling the static meathod

```
QProcess::startDetached
```

But that fails on me too.

Comment: I don't use QT, but could it be a permission problem? If you don't want to use QProcess, you could always use [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have messed around with those but the program doesn't even start. It just fails as if it cant find the exe. But its there.

Comment: Sysinternals' Process monitor utility might help you find out what's wrong - it will show the error code returned from the Windows API being used (I assume that's `CreateProcess()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your program is 32-bit and running under 64-bit Windows. `PnPUtil.exe` is not in `c:\windows\system32` when you are running a 32-bit program, that's why `QProcess` fails to start it. It's somewhere else, for example, mine is located at `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-pnputil_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_ee22229c907e8ce2`. You can run `c:\windows\system32\PnPUtil.exe` in Command Prompt because `cmd.exe` is a 64-bit program.

You can try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253713/what-is-pnputil-exe-location-in-64bit-systems) or [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/e7f40b9f-215e-4272-b882-6b18f6693bb1/createprocess-and-iscsicliexe-fails-on-64-bit-pc).

**UPDATE 1**

Sample code that runs PnPUtil and Ping under 32-bit or 64-bit Windows.

```
#include <QtCore>

void run( QString command, QStringList args )
{
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
    //proc->setWorkingDirectory ( "C:\\windows\\" );
    qDebug() << "\n===========================================";
    qDebug() << "Running " << command << args.join(' ');
    qDebug() << (QFile::exists(command) ? "File exists: " : "File may not exist:") << command;
    int exitCode = proc->execute(command, args );
    proc->waitForFinished();
    qDebug() << "\nResult";
    qDebug() << "======";
    qDebug() << "proc->execute()    =" << exitCode;
    qDebug() << "proc->exitCode()   =" << proc->exitCode();
    qDebug() << "proc->exitStatus() =" << proc->exitStatus();    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QStringList pnpUtilArg("-?");
    QStringList pingArg("google.com");

    run( qgetenv( "WINDIR" ) + "\\sysnative\\pnputil.exe", pnpUtilArg);
    run( qgetenv( "WINDIR" ) + "\\system32\\pnputil.exe", pnpUtilArg);
    run( qgetenv( "WINDIR" ) + "\\system32\\ping.exe", pingArg);
    run( "ping.exe", pingArg);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. Another simple hacky workaround would be to try executing `c:\windows\sysnative\pnputil.exe`.  I don't know if this would be a good idea in general though.

Comment: Tried running it on a 32 bit system and it didn't work.

Comment: @Snhp9, did you mean you can't run `c:\windows\sysnative\pnputil.exe` under 32-bit Windows? Well, `pnputil` is not located there under 32-bit Window hahaha. I guess your 32-bit program needs to know the bit-ness of the OS it's running under. Try this: 1) Under 32-bit Windows, run `c:\windows\system32\pnputil.exe` 2) Under 64-bit Windows, run `c:\windows\sysnative\pnputil.exe`

Comment: @Snhp9: On how to check the OS's bit-ness, try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045163/getting-runtime-architecture-information-in-qt). Another solution without caring the bit-ness could be: run `c:\windows\sysnative\pnputil.exe` if it exists. Otherwise run `c:\windows\system32\pnputil.exe`

Comment: I tried both I hardcoded the path for the 32 bit. Compiled the program in 32 bit and then ran it on a 32 bit computer. I did the same for 64 bit aswell. It was doing this with ping.exe even. Even If I specified the full path to ping it would not work. The only way I could get it to work was put ping.exe in the same directory as the program and that worked. I cant do that with pnputils because of all the dependencys.

Comment: @Snhp9, I added a sample code. The same 32-bit executable runs PnPUtil and ping under 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. Try it out.

Comment: Yep that seemed to work out. But it wasn't because of the location of the 32bit and 64 bit. Because with my old QProcess code it wasnt working for iether 32 bit or 64 bit locations. And I found that on my 64 bit pc that with your example I can run the pnputils in the 32bit location and not the 64 bit location.